# Android Application runs but nothing is drawn on canvas

Tags: android, eclipse, android-canvas

I wrote a Compass example that came out of an Android application tutorial book and wrote the custom view, methods, and such, but nothing is being drawn on the screen when the app runs.

Here is the class:

```
package com.example.compass;

import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

public class CompassView extends View {

private float bearing;
private Paint markerPaint;
private Paint textPaint;
private Paint circlePaint;
private String northString;
private String eastString;
private String southString;
private String westString;
private int textHeight;

public CompassView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initCompassView();
}

public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initCompassView();
}

public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet ats, int defaultStyle) {
    super(context, ats, defaultStyle);
    initCompassView();
}

protected void initCompassView() {
    setFocusable(true);

    Resources r = this.getResources();

    circlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    circlePaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.background_color));
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

    northString = r.getString(R.string.cardinal_north);
    eastString = r.getString(R.string.cardinal_east);
    southString = r.getString(R.string.cardinal_south);
    westString = r.getString(R.string.cardinal_west);

    textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    textPaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.text_color));
    textHeight = (int)textPaint.measureText("yY");

    markerPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    markerPaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.marker_color));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int mMeasuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int mMeasuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

    int px = mMeasuredWidth/2;
    int py = mMeasuredHeight/2;

    int radius = Math.min(px, py);

    canvas.drawCircle(px, py, radius, circlePaint);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(-bearing, px, py);

    int textWidth = (int) textPaint.measureText("W");
    int cardinalX = px-textWidth/2;
    int cardinalY = py-radius+textHeight;

    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(px, py-radius, px, py-radius+10, markerPaint);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(0, textWidth);

        if (i%6 == 0) {
            String dirString = "";
            switch (i) {
            case(0):{
                dirString = northString;
                int arrowY = 2*textHeight;
                canvas.drawLine(px, arrowY, px-5, 3*textHeight, markerPaint);
                canvas.drawLine(px, arrowY, px+5, 3*textHeight, markerPaint);
                break;
                }
                case(6): dirString = eastString; break;
                case(12): dirString = southString; break;
                case(18): dirString = westString; break;
            }
            canvas.drawText(dirString, cardinalX, cardinalY, textPaint);
        }

        else if (i%3==0) {
            String angle = String.valueOf(i*15);
            float angleTextWidth = textPaint.measureText(angle);

            int angleTextX = (int)(px-angleTextWidth/2);
            int angleTextY = py-radius+textHeight;
            canvas.drawText(angle, angleTextX, angleTextY, textPaint);
        }
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.rotate(15, px, py);
    }
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int measuredWidth = measure(widthMeasureSpec);
    int measuredHeight = measure(heightMeasureSpec);

    int d = Math.min(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);

    setMeasuredDimension(d, d);
}

private int measure(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;

    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
        result = 200;
    } 
    else {
        result = specSize;
    }

    return result;
}

public void setBearing(float _bearing) {
    bearing = _bearing;
    sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED);
}

public float getBearing() {
    return bearing;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(final AccessibilityEvent event) {
    super.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
    if (isShown()) {
        String bearingStr = String.valueOf(bearing);
        if (bearingStr.length() > AccessibilityEvent.MAX_TEXT_LENGTH)
            bearingStr = bearingStr.substring(0, AccessibilityEvent.MAX_TEXT_LENGTH);

        event.getText().add(bearingStr);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

I don't get any logcat errors; it does however display this (which might be relevant):

```
04-01 18:41:57.163: D/gralloc_goldfish(583): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

However, after seeing this I added GPU emulation hardware to my emulator and selected the "Yes" option, but this message keeps showing up.

What could be the cause of nothing displaying on the screen? I can also post xml files if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the cause: called getMode a second time instead of getSize... I feel dumb now.